# Can random forest be applied to predict an event rate for a time interval, for the following problem statement?

Tags: classification, random-forest, rare-events

I have to predict which of the agents (in a direct selling business) could become sales leaders. This prediction has to be done just before every sales cycle (there are 2 week cycles across the year, hence 26 cycles).
My current data prep approach has been to create every transaction variable (like total sales, total orders, #cycles in which the agent was active) till one  sales cycle before (in which the agent becomes a sales leader) or till a fixed number of sales cycles beyond which I don't consider an agent for data inclusion or prediction. I average these aggregated variables out by taking a ratio with number of sales cycles in which the rep participated

Other than such transaction variables, I have demographics and the information for the agents who recruited these agents. As my dependent variable, I have a flag which is '1' for all agents who became leaders and '0' for agents who didn't.

I use weighted random forest on this (unbalanced data with ~7% event rate) 930,000 row agent dataset with one row per agent. This approach isn't giving me good results on training and validation pieces (class accuracy of 85% each but fp/(fp+tp) = 80%). When I predict on a single sales cycle, there are a lot of false positives (almost 50% of the data and class accuracy is also near 55%). I tried proportional hazard survival model as well, and used sales_cycle*Leader_Flag as the dependent with the same covariate(s) but the false positives are still a lot..

Could someone help me explain what could be going wrong? This is a similar business problem to churn, but with a positive outcome